# Get the Servlet Request object in a POJO class

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I need to get the current page URL in a POJO that is being called from an Acegi class (need to add some custom logic for the app I'm working on) and need to retrieve the HttpServletRequest so that I can get the subdomain of the URL (on which the logic is based).

I've tried to add:

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

...

public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
}

public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    return request;
}
```

However when I try to use the request object in my code, it is null.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or how I can better go about doing this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If the bean is request scoped you can autowire the HttpServletRequest like you are doing.

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class Foo {
    @Autowired private HttpServletRequest request;

    //
}
```

Otherwise you can get the current request as follows:

```
    ServletRequestAttributes sra = (ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    HttpServletRequest req = sra.getRequest();
```

This uses thread-local under the covers.

If you are using Spring MVC that's all you need.   If you are not using Spring MVC then you will need to register a [RequestContextListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html) or [RequestContextFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html) in your `web.xml`.

Comment: what is the spring 1.2.5 counter part for the same ,as these classes are not available in spring 1.2.5