# Jersey + Spring Context Outside of Controller

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Spring bean that needs information from the request, but isn't directly called from the controller (although it could be - but I'd like to try this without it)

Basically, my API makes requests to other services over thrift. When it makes the request, there's a service call like this:

```
authenticationService.authenticate(null, "username", "password");
```

The first parameter (the `null`) is usually a "placeholder" instance of a request context. The request context contains information about the user making the request, the originating IP, etc. This way, I get all of the details about the original caller without letting my API infrastructure leak into the backend.

However, to do this, I have an `InvocationHandler` that intercepts method calls made against a proxy of my service interfaces. Inside of that proxy handler, I have a `RequestContextFactory` wired in that creates instances of a `RequestContext`. Inside of this factory, I need to get information from the request. Particularly, the `SecurityContext`, so I can identify the user making the call.

Right now, I have:

```
@Provider
@Component
public class WebRequestContextFactory implements RequestContextFactory {
    @Context private ContainerRequest containerRequest;

    public RequestContext createRequestContext() {

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `containerRequest` is always `null`.

Comment: Have you tried calling RequestContextListener.getRequestAttributes().getRequest() per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6301038/1325237 ? It seems like that should get the request associated to the current thread.

Comment: What is the package of `WebRequestContextFactory` class. Is it under the package where jersey property `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` points to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ServletRequestAttributes` to get the information from the `request` and the `ServletRequestAttributes` can be obtained from `RequestContextHolder`:

```
ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .currentRequestAttributes();
```

If the request is processed by the Spring `DispatcherServlet`, there is no need of any special setup. `DispatcherServlet` already expose all relevant state. But if the requests are processed outside of Spring's `DispatcherServlet`, then you need to add `javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener` in your application's web.xml file:

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

This will associate the request with the current thread and the associated request attributes can then be retrieved via `RequestContextHolder`.

Comment: While this isn't quite what I was hoping for, I think it comes closes to what I was trying to achieve. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*In a slightly different scenario, the following worked for me. YMMV.*

Replace this:

```
@Context private ContainerRequest containerRequest;
```

With this:

```
@Context private javax.inject.Provider<ContainerRequest> containerRequestProvider;
```

Then at the place in your code where you need the `ContainerRequest`:

```
ContainerRequest containerRequest = containerRequestProvider.get();
```

Code sample that pointed me toward this solution: https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-okhttp-interceptor-demo/blob/b3b2da00b284e75011ea780fb37b555ea581ac96/src/main/java/com/example/stackoverflow/client/UserFactory.java

Answer (score 0):

For Authentication, it's better to use container realm, or to use normal servlet.

And for Authorization, you can use Application or rest servlet. And in this kind of process, you can find the info from context annotation. Here's sample:

```
(@Context final SecurityContext sc, @Context Request request) {
        logMe(sc);
...
    }

    private void logMe(final SecurityContext sc) {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("User=" + sc.getUserPrincipal().getName());
            LOGGER.info("User Role?=" + sc.isUserInRole("user"));
            LOGGER.info("Auth way=" + sc.getAuthenticationScheme());
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.debug(e);
        }
    }
```

Or:

```
(@Context final SecurityContext sc, @Context ContainerRequestContext request) {
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you could so quickly argue that "it's better." That being said, I have OAuth compliant controllers in my application that make service calls to the backend and would much prefer to keep it that way. However, this has nothing to do with the question being asked. The question is about injecting request context information into a spring bean that isn't a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a access token that contains your desire information such as IP Address, user name etc. During the authentication phase create a custom token and put this token into spring security context. Later you could extract this token from other places such in your proxy classes. After extracting the token you validate or whatever you want.

**Creating custom object and token:**

```
public class CustomAuthentication {

  private String userId;

  private String password;

  private String ipAddress;
}


public class CustomAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

    private CustomAuthentication customAuthentication;

    public CustomAuthenticationToken(MobiLabAuthentication authentication,
      Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
      super(authorities);
      this.customAuthentication = authentication;
      setAuthenticated(true);
    }

    public CustomAuthenticationToken() {
      super(null);
      setAuthenticated(false);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
     return customAuthentication.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
      return customAuthentication.getUserId();
    }

}
```

**Store the token into Spring security context**

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
authorities.add(new RestUserAuthrity("YOUR_APP_ROLE"));

//Extract IP , user and pass etc and construct CustomAuthentication instance
CustomAuthentication authentication = new CustomAuthentication(.....)

CustomAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new CustomAuthenticationToken(
     authentication, authorities);

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
```

**Validate security information from the Proxy bean**

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();

if (authentication instanceof CustomAuthenticationToken) {
  CustomAuthenticationToken token = (CustomAuthenticationToken) authentication;
 //now you can get your ip address from token
}
```